# NameError in MoviesController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I generated movie model, and a movies folder to Controllers. 
I deleted index.html in public_html folder, because I want start the movie page, so I edited the routers.rb file with 2 new line:

```
  map.resources :movies
  map.index '/', :controller=>"movies", :action=>"index"
```

I start the application, but something wrong. The error message: 
NameError in MoviesController#index
uninitialized constant MoviesController

I think the problem is in the controller part.
the folder structure:

+controllers

-movie
 --_index.erb
 --index.html.erb (with  <%= render :partial=>"index", :collection=>@movies%>)

application.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your folder structure is odd.

You should have the following **folders** in **app**: controllers, helpers, models and views.

You should have the following **files** in **app/controllers**: application_controller.rb, movies_controller.rb

You should have the following **files** in **app/views/movies**: index.html.erb and _index.html.erb (though it's a bit odd to use a partial like this).